# Android crashes on calling FragmentTransaction Replace method?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

What I am trying to do is to use only one Activity as a host for many fragments such as the activity will host only one fragment at a time and the fragments should attached to the activity in a certain order.
My Fragment code:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{

    //some code here to instantiate FirstFragment here.

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onFirstFragmentFinished(position);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface FirstFragmentListener {
        public void onFirstFragmentFinished(int position);
    }
}
```

Simply, in each fragment I have a button when pressed it will get the host activity and call the implemented method of `FirstFragmentListener` interface.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragmentListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTra = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       fragmentTra .replace(R.id.main_layout, new FirstFragment());
       fragmentTra.commit(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirstFragmentFinished(int position)
    {
        if(position == 1)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTra = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTra .replace(R.id.main_layout, new SecondFragment());
            fragmentTra.commit(); 
        }
    }
}
```

When the activity is created, always replace whatever inside this activity with FirstFragment layout.
When the FirstFragment finishes its work and the button on that fragment is pressed, it will call the implemented method of FirstFragment interface on this activity and then check the position for some value, if the condition is correct then go and replace FirstFragment with The SecondFragment instance.
The app is crashing when `commit()` method is called.

Comment: Stack Trace? Also, are you sure your function name is `commit()` as you use `commi()` in the code?

Comment: It is just a typo error when I wrote the question. Sorry for this. any way this will arise a compiler error, that is, the application will not even run at all before I fix this because commi() is not exist.

Comment: please provide your error stack

Comment: @MinaFawzy thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at my stack trace and I found this exception:

```
com.example.exchange.msbexchange E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.exchange.msbexchange, PID: 17975
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.exchange.msbexchange.MainActivity@1e7d93b must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
at com.example.exchange.msbexchange.CurrencyFragment.onAttach(CurrencyFragment.java:83)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1030)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

It is obviousely because my MainActivity does not implement the interface of the SecondFragment Class. I did not know this is mandatory for the fragments to work. I just need to implement the interface and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment you need View to bind with fragment like this :

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(position == 1){
                     SecondFragment secondFrag= new SecondFragment();
                     getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.main_layout, secondFrag)
                           .addToBackStack(null)
                           .commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually my code was exactly as you are suggesting in your answer but unfortunately it is not working.  I updated my question.

Comment: okay, but why don't you open your secondFragment from Your Current Fragment see My updated code

Comment: I will give it a try but can you explain how this is different from putting the same code in a method and calling this method instead of executing the code directly? is it because the method is called on the Activity itself or because of another reason?

Comment: reason is, instead calling that method which is define in Activity to open another fragment you can directly open it from here

Answer (score 0):

Use of your onFirstFragmentFinished is wrong. Look at official doc:
[android-comunication-activity-ffragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

It is prefer to Override onAttach() method.

Answer (score 0):

you need implement your interface `FirstFragmentListener` in onAttach in fragment

```
FirstFragmentListener mCallback;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (FirstFragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

then use it as you do on click or what ever you want

Comment: You can see my answer. I cannot make it accepted before 2 days. It is because I did not implement the SecondFragment interface in my MainActivity class.

Comment: the issue you must implement the interface before you use it , this why I implement it in onAttach

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get position variable from? It seems that this variable does not have value...

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onFirstFragmentFinished(position);
    }
});
return view;
```

}

Comment: See my answer. I cannot make it accepted before 2 days :-( .
It has nothing to do with position variable.